# How do we go about solidifying policy change?

Tags: support

Over the history of this site, there has been repeated discussion of whether distilling and other "non-brewing" activities should be allowed:

- [How to deal with questions/answers about potentially illegal activities?](https://homebrew.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31/12609)
- [Ignoring legality, is Homebrew Stack Exchange going to encompass distilling?](https://homebrew.meta.stackexchange.com/q/162/12609)
- [Are questions that do not involve any brewing on topic here?](https://homebrew.meta.stackexchange.com/q/404/12609)
- [Is this question about sweet liqueur off-topic?](https://homebrew.meta.stackexchange.com/q/450/12609)
- [Distilling questions](https://homebrew.meta.stackexchange.com/q/466/12609)

The most upvoted answers on each of these questions seem to me to suggest that the community overall does, and always has, supported the inclusion of such topics.  However, there still seems to be an assumption that this is not allowed (likely based on the proposal-phase discussion where people were weary of its legality, which I feel has been more than addressed since then).

All of that said, my question is less about this particular topic and more around what steps are required do the following:

1. Officially determine whether the community at large would in fact like a change to be made.
2. Define the changes that should be made to the site to make this more explicit (e.g. updating the tour information to explicitly include whether or not distilling is allowed and/or possibly changing the name of the site to something more clearly inclusive).
3. Enact the changes once they are agreed upon.

Is there an official process for this?  How do we avoid spending another 8 years debating this point without any definitive action?

Comment: Is this something that maybe @Shog9 could help with?

Comment: Or maybe @Catija?

Comment: Things move slow here on Stack Exchange... No movement over on the Alcohol stack either.

Comment: It seems there is basically the three of us discussing this. I have bumped the questions on the site asking if people are aware of meta to try get more people over here so we can sample their opinions.

Answer (score 1):

Funny you bring this up. We were having the same discussion over at Alcohol. Nothing happened, but I think we need to turn homebrew and alcohol into production and non-production stacks. https://alcohol.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234/keep-the-booze-on-alcohol-and-we-will-deal-with-beer-and-wine-making-at-homebrew

Comment: I like the idea of production vs enjoyment. But There is always overlap, and I owuld never exclude someone from asking a question here like - what glass should I use for this homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

I have always been happy to answer questions mearly as you have a question here is an answer to your academic curiosity; as legality differs so much on distillation and brewing, often not even country to country but state or smaller district within a country. You have to warn people about these aspects as many people are oblivious the risk both leagal and practical.

I like the idea of production, vs non-production rgarding alcoholic beverages. There is always a grey area in the middle, like what glass should I serve this beer I made in, could bleed in between both but making alcohol in some form => homebrew, drinking alcohol purchased => alcohol.

Quick answers to questions posed.

- How to deal with questions/answers about potentially illegal activities?

  ```
   Answer but advise on potential legality/illigality.
  ```
- Ignoring legality, is Homebrew Stack Exchange going to encompass distilling?

  ```
   I think it should.
  ```
- Are questions that do not involve any brewing on topic here?

  ```
   How to enjoy beer/wime/mead/etc... you made on topic, how to drink a beer you purchased off-topic.
  ```
- Is this question about sweet liqueur off-topic?

  ```
   it is about production of an alcoholic drink so I would say on topic 100%.
  ```
- Distilling questions

  ```
   on topic as manufacturing alcoholic beverages.
  ```